# Using setLeft/setRight methods on new textview

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

I'm working with TextViews progammatically and I need to dynamically add new views and set their left/top position in the RelativeLayout parent.
What I'm doing is something like this:

```
RelativeLayout global=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.global);
TextView view=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.root);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
final TextView childView=new TextView(view.getContext());
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, view.getId());
childView.setLayoutParams(lp);
childView.setId(childView.getId()+1);
childView.setText("TRY STRING");
childView.setTextSize(view.getTextSize());
childView.setWidth(view.getWidth());
childView.setLeft(view.getLeft()+interval);
global.addView(childView);
```

Basically, I have a textview in a certain position (which is called view) and I'm trying to create a new textview above the existing one and on the same left position.
Although the getLeft() method correctly returns the left position of view, childView happens to have the left field set to zero, and appears at the left end of the screen when i add it to the RelativeLayout.
It looks like it's completely ignoring the setLeft method!
Can anyone explain why?
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

public final void setLeft (int left)

Added in API level 11
Sets the left position of this view relative to its parent. This method is meant to be called by the layout system and should not generally be called otherwise, because the property may be changed at any time by the layout.

Parameters
left    The bottom of this view, in pixels.

---

most likely the left value is being set by the layout every time it is drawn and overrides the value that you are setting on your view.

android layouts are very XML ish even when doing it programmatically.

try using

```
lp.setMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom);
```

..or some other method that won't be undone when the layout is drawn

Comment: Thank you!! setMargins actually works fine for this kind of issues